# Wix Spam Filter

Tags: spam-prevention, monitoring, wix

I created a site on Wix where people can post in specific groups, similar to how Facebook operates with Facebook Groups. However, as the number of people on my site grows, I want to be able to have the system identify key words that they shouldn't be using, like swear words, so those posts can be reviewed by myself and other admins.

I haven't been able to find a solution for this on any of Wix's help pages and I'm not seeing a functionality on the editor's site to implement a filter or a catch or anything. Any ideas?